# Bounty not subtracted after answer is deleted

Tags: support, bounties

I had a bounty awarded for an answer I gave. After I deleted said answer I still retained the bounty award (ie: total rep not subtracted), even though the rep audit is showing a different score (ie: without the bounty).

Is this intentional?

Comment: May I ask, why you delete an answer, which was considered bounty-worthy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your reputation audit is showing that you are losing the bounty reputation, then you are losing the bounty reputation. Deleting a post does not cause a direct effect on your displayed reputation, requiring a reputation recalculation to update it to the correct value. This would be the same as if you gained/lost reputation from votes prior to deleting a post.

Comment: It's been a couple of weeks already.

Comment: @Null Reputation recalcs aren't an automatic process. You have to manually request one, usually by flagging one of your posts for moderator attention and asking for a recalc. The only mechanical occurrence of a recalc is if you are involved in a serial voting incident. Time is irrelevant.

Comment: Look, @Grace, look what Juan did: Two tiny sentences. Case closed. Your sentences are neither tiny, nor are they two.

Comment: @Ladybug This time, I'm keeping this length of 3 sentences. I think explaining *why* the reputation is out of sync is valuable.

Comment: @Grace: You missed the *tiny* part!

Comment: @Ladybug With this specific post, trying to trim words from my sentences is equivalent to micro-optimizations. If people can't be bothered to read a slightly elongated answer that has different characteristics, then it's my loss and I accept that.

Comment: @Grace: There is no hope you :(

Comment: @Ladybug. I totally agree. He should be ashamed.

Answer (score 2):

The rep audit is the real reputation.

You are out of sync, but will get re-synced when your reputation is recalculated.

Comment: I see. It's just that rep from upvotes gets subtracted very quickly after the post is deleted.

Comment: @Null, are you sure? aren't you getting confused with "removing a vote"? (that is indeed instantaneous)