# What causes reputation to go out of sync?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Soon after I joined SO, there was a discrepancy between the reputation shown in the rep audit ( https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ) and the reputation on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception). IIRC the one on the audit is the "real" reputation. At first the site used to show I had 50 *more* points than I actually had, [because of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59785/bounty-not-subtracted-after-answer-is-deleted).

The gap got smaller and smaller, and now the site says I have 9 *less* points than the rep audit.
What causes the rep to go out of sync, and more specifically, why does it tend to go down (ie site shows less than "real" rep)? The only reason I can think of is:

- My downvotes to deleted posts don't get recalculated.

But from my calculations it wouldn't be enough to create this much discrepancy. So what could be the other reasons?

Comment: It's undocumented. Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43609/reputation-graph-doesnt-take-the-new-rep-rules-into-account-apparently-there-a

Comment: This does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Answer (score 4):

Deletion of posts, deletion of users, are common reasons.

Comment: But deletion of users only affects the rep because their posts are deleted too, right?

Comment: @null all their votes are deleted as well

Comment: how about migrated or undeleted posts?